# Set Field Value Workflow

Tags: workflow, netsuite

Customer has a custom field (Payment Type) with drop down list of 4 different payment (Cash, Check, Forward Transfer and ACH/Bank File) options on Vendor Payment page. Customer does not want the Check # field to auto fill if Cash, Forward Transfer or ACH/Bank File chosen. Created workflow with Set Field Value action but not working.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Leigh. It's better to add the piece of your code and not to ask the solution from the scratch!

Answer (score 0):

Use client script - Field Change Action - This is SuiteScript 2.0

- Set Field Value Check# to blank

function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {

```
            log.debug('inside fieldChanged');
            var name = scriptContext.fieldId;
            var vendorRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;

            if (name == "custbody_payemnt_type") {
                var payType = vendorRecord .getValue({
                    fieldId: 'custbody_payment_type'
                }); 
                if(payType == "1") { //cash 
                  vendorRecord.setValue({
                       fieldId: 'custbody_check_num',
                       value: '',
                       ignoreFieldChange: false,
                       forceSyncSourcing: true
                    });

                }
             }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just create another Set Field Value workflow action and set "To Be Printed" to true. Netsuite will clear the Check# field for you.